# Обращение к 2 соседним элементам std::set

Tags: c++, множества

Возникла задача, в которой надо обращаться с двумя соседними элементами множества `set`. Такой вопрос: как это сделать? Гуглил, нигде не нашел информации по этому поводу, уже сомневаюсь, что так вообще можно делать. Например, у вектора этот вопрос решается так: `v[i]` - `i`-й элемент, а `v[i+1]` - соседний элемент. Можно ли делать что-то аналогичное во множестве? Метод `find()` не предлагать, так как я не знаю, какие числа лежат в контейнерах.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь итераторами. Если итератор `it` указывает на нужный вам элемент `set`, например, найденный с помощью `find()` или, скажем, первый элемент, полученный с помощью `begin()`, то после выполнения `++it` этот итератор будет указывать на следующий элемент контейнера.

Comment: Хм...самое время узнать, что такое итераторы. Спасибо

Comment: Ну так что такое по сути STL? Контейнеры + итераторы. И немного утилит :)

Comment: и Алгоритмы! Но только о них все забывают и пишут все ручками. Или обзывают их "утилитами"

Comment: @KoVadim Ну, алгоритмы для работы с контейнерами и итераторами я отношу к итераторам и контейнерам :)  Ну, а остальное - так, утилиты :)

Comment: алгоритмы могут работать и с обычными массивами, где нет ни контейнеров, ни итераторов.

Comment: @Abyx Жаль, что об этом не знает, например, Джосаттис, который описывает ее в своей книге о стандартной библиотеку C++, или, скажем, *член комитета ISO С++* Готтшлинг, который пишет об STL как о части стандартной библиотеки C++ в своей книге...

Comment: @KoVadim А что такое массив, как не частный случай контейнера, и указатель - как не частный случай итератора?...

Comment: фишка в том, что есть STL, который написан Степановым и Ли (а там даже std::string не было) и есть STL, который часть стандарта. Первое - действительно сейчас устарело.

Comment: @Abyx, вероятнее всего, что с этим не хотят бороться, т.к. подобная борьба не имеет смысла. Поэтому многие зарубежные именитые C++ деятели говоря STL, имеют в виду именно стандартную библиотеку. Сейчас уже не важно, что это когда-то представляло собой вполне конкретную библиотеку. В наше время, когда говорят STL, все понимают о чём речь. Тот же Ниблер, говоря о range-based части библиотеки, называет её STLv2.

Comment: @Abyx Вот адрес Готтшлинга - peter.gottschling@simunova.com - напишите, он почту читает и отвечает :) Вот - web14@josuttis.com - Джосаттиса.

Comment: @Abyx Вот из книги Страуструпа - там еще много таких упоминаний - http://i92.fastpic.ru/big/2017/0807/56/0d018c994e1bc4a147b73edf33947656.jpg. Его e-mail дать? Простите, но Страуструпу я доверяю немного больше...